# Run program from c++ source which required multiple input

Tags: c++, interactive

I need to run [RNAeval](http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/%7Eronny/RNA/RNAeval.html) (executable) from a c++ code and read the output of `RNAeval`. I found a code which can run a command and read the output.

```
string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

But [RNAeval](http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/%7Eronny/RNA/RNAeval.html) doesn't take any command line argument. Instead i need to provide input after run the program (similar to `bc` in linux).

## example

```
RNAeval [enter]
input1 [enter]
input2 [enter]
return output by RNAeval and exit
```

How can i do this from c++?

**System:**

```
Linux
g++
gcc
```

## Edit

```
string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "w");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    fprintf(pipe,"%s\n","acgt");
    fprintf(pipe,"%s\n","(())");
    fprintf(pipe,"%s\n","@");
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    } 
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;

}
```

Comment: You can do that using echo "command\ncommand2" | program as your param, if you are using *nix systems.

Comment: It's doesn't work (input1\input2). It's doesn't take command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

popen returns a FILE object that you could use to write RNAEval's input stream. You can use fprintf to write commands to the process after you do the popen, then read in the results.

Comment: It works, But another problem. Now program doesn't terminate. result returns correctly, but doesn't terminate. When i use "r" flag it terminate successfully.

Comment: It looks like you can only read OR write using popen. No read and write. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171552/popen-simultaneous-read-and-write, that may have a solution for you.