# Calling a different program and passing it arguments

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arguments

I created a random integer generator program. It takes in two arguments, a max number and a min number, and spits out a random integer within that range including both ends.

I am creating simulation programs in which I need random integer numbers and I want to be able to call the randomizer program and pass the max and mins I need for the simulation program to it and then return the random number to the simulation.

I just do not know and can not find the code I would need to write in the simulation to bring up the randomizer AND pass it the max and min values.

Thank you!

Comment: This is what a function or class (depending on the situation) is for, not an entire program to call within others.

Comment: Can you atleast write the method signature?

Comment: You can use [fork](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/fork.2.html) to spawn a child process on *nix ...

Comment: `std::stringstream ss; ss << filename << ".exe " << min << " " << max;  system(ss.str().c_str());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific question, you should consider using `popen()`.  Make sure to call `pclose()` after your are finished reading in your result.

```
FILE *input = popen("program -and args", "r");
if (input) {
  // read the input
  pclose(input);
} else {
  perror("popen");
  // handle error
}
```

If the program is reading its arguments from standard input, and then outputting the result to  its standard output, you will need to create a bidirectional version of `popen`. Assuming you have a POSIX compliant OS, `socketpair` could be used to create your bidirectional channel (alternatively, you could make two calls to `pipe`). Then you would implement the functionality using `fork` and then one of the `exec` variants. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884103/can-popen-make-bidirectional-pipes-like-pipe-fork).

But, as suggested by others, you should really just incorporate the functionality of your random number generator into your program as a function.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a library from your random generator and link against it.  Otherwise, you can look up the [`execv()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).