# Executing line counting bash command (wc -l) inside a c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I want to calculate the no of lines of data file before declaring a global array. I know in terminal if I execute `wc -l filename`, I get the number of lines. How do I use that command `(wc -l filename)` and store its result into a int type variable inside a c++ program? When I use the following code:
 `int NT=system(" wc -l file.d");` 
I get `NT=0.`

**How to get the no. of lines in file.d in NT?**

Comment: Why use add a dependency against an external program for a task that you can do yourself in three lines of C++ code?

Comment: No, It would be problematic for me. I need to declare an 3d global array, say A[n][3][3], where n would be the no. of lines in that data file. To declare the array globally, I need to know the value of n beforehand.

Comment: @SatadruBag ‘Beforehand’ as in before compiling? This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Google "how to count number of lines in c++" and use that instead.

Comment: Probably [`popen`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10938130/315052) will suffice.

Comment: @SatarduBag: besides the fact that using `std::vector` having the array grow while you are filling it is a non-issue, what I'm saying is that you can count the lines (without actually parsing them) *before* allocating the array. By the way, global arrays are statically allocated anyway (you cannot decide their size at runtime depending from the output of `wc`), so I don't see what you hope to so here.

Comment: Matteo Italia: yes, I forgot that even if I know no. of lines beforehand, I can not declare a global 3d array. Can I do it using a pointer? Can you help?

Comment: @SatadruBag: make a `struct` for each row (something like `struct DataPoint { int d[3][3]; }`); then for each line you read fill one instance of such structure, and push it into an `std::vector<DataPoint>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can get the number of lines in a file is by using *getline*:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream in("file.d");
    int lines = 0;
    string s;
    while (getline(in, s))
    {
        ++lines;
    }
    cout << lines << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT...**

A more efficient way (if you only want the count and don't want to use any of the data) is to use istream::ignore, as pointed out by Matteo Italia.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream in("in.txt");
    int lines = 0;
    char endline_char = '\n';
    while (in.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), in.widen(endline_char)))
    {
        ++lines;
    }
    cout << lines << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Either way will output the number of lines in a file called "file.d". You can compare its output to that of 'wc -l'.

Comment: This does solve the problem, but you are copying all those lines for no reason. Use `fstream::ignore()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What should be a fairly efficient solution, though it's not portable outside of POSIX systems (read: You'd have to rewrite to use WinAPI equivalent calls on Windows), as it avoids the need to actually construct objects, perform explicit reads for each line, etc. Aside from the `mmap` work (much of which can be factored out at least), it's basically a one-liner.

I don't really recommend this in general (your problem should be solved by just using `std::vector` or the like so your data structure can grow dynamically to match the number of lines), but I'm putting it here if you're curious.

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const char* map_whole_file(const char *filename, size_t& map_size);

int main(...) {
    const char *filename = ...;  // From argv, constant, whatever
    size_t map_size;

    const char *data = map_whole_file(filename, map_size);

    // Number of lines is count of newline characters, +1 if final line not
    // terminated with newline
    size_t numlines = std::count(data, data+map_size, '\n') + (data[map_size-1] != '\n');

    munmap(data, map_size);
}

const char* map_whole_file(const char *filename, size_t& map_size) {
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        ...handle_error...;

    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)           /* To obtain file size */
        ...handle_error...;

    // Cast only needed because it's C++
    const char *data = (const char *)mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED)
        ...handle_error...;

    close(fd); // Don't need fd after mapping done

    // Optionally, posix_madvise(data, sb.st_size, POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED);
    // or the like will hint the OS to aggressively page in the file, so
    // count is less likely to be delayed by disk I/O

    map_size = sb.st_size;
    return data;
}
```